# How to fail a job based on ${PIPESTATUS[0]}

Tags: bash, ubuntu, github, jestjs, github-actions

Jest returns a nonzero exit code when a unit test fails

But the exit code gets suppressed when I tee the output out

How can I fail a job based on the linux environment variable ${PIPESTATUS[0]}?

I verified that PIPESTATUS[0] has a nonzero value

I tried exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}, but that doesn't work

I tried if statements, but might not have the syntax correctly

```
  - name: Install & test
    id: unit_coverage_status
    run: |
      npm ci
      npm run test-coverage | tee ./unit-coverage.txt
      echo "Test coverage exit code: ${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
      if ${PIPESTATUS[0]} == 0;
      then
        echo "Unit tests passed"            
      else
        echo "Unit tests failed"
        exit 1
      fi
```

After the txt is generated, am going to use the step below to add the results to the PR

```
  - name: Jest integration coverage comment
    uses: MishaKav/jest-coverage-comment@main
    with:
      coverage-path: ./int-coverage.txt       
      title: Integration Test Coverage
```

Comment: Where is `PIPESTATUS` defined?

Comment: It's a linux Array variable holding exit status(es) of last executed foreground pipe https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html @matt schuchard

Comment: Sorry I had this confused with another CI platform. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: I switched to a different plugin - one which does not require the output to be teeed out https://github.com/ArtiomTr/jest-coverage-report-action

Answer (score 0):

I was able to capture the test failure by adding  `&& exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to my command.

```
  - name: Install & test
    id: unit_coverage_status
    run: |
      npm ci
      npm run test-coverage | tee ./unit-coverage.txt && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

The coverage comment is only generated if the test passes. If the test are failing, I am more concerned with showing that than I am showing coverage for it.